# Proving big O of statement

Tags: math, big-o, proof

I am having a hard time proving that `n^k` is `O(2^n)` for all `k`. I tried taking `lg2` of both sides and have `k*lgn=n`, but this is wrong. I am not sure how else I can prove this.

Comment: Can you give us a few more details? First, I assume you're talking about computing n^k. What's your level of abstraction for the operations? Number of multiplications? Number of additions?

Comment: There aren't any levels of abstraction - this is for algorithm efficiency proof. I need to prove that 'n' to the power of 'k' will always be O(2^n) - big O notation.

Comment: Migrate to math.SE or cstheory.SE?

Comment: Expressions don't have complexity - only algorithms or functions. Anyway, this is off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: And in any case not true for `k = 0,1`.

Comment: This doesn't belong on cstheory, since it's not a research-level topic.

Comment: @Keith- How is this claim false for k = 0 or 1?  n^0 = 1 is definitely O(2^n), though it's a horribly weak bound, and n^1 = n is also definitely O(2^n), although it is a very weak bound.

Answer (score 3):

To show that n<sup>k</sup> is O(2<sup>n</sup>), note that

> n<sup>k</sup> = (2<sup>lg n</sup>)<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k lg n</sup>

So now you want to find an n<sub>0</sub> and c such that for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>,

> 2<sup>k lg n</sup> ≤ c 2<sup>n</sup>

Now, let's let c = 1 and then consider what happens when n = 2<sup>m</sup> for some m.  If we do this, we get

> 2<sup>k lg n</sup> ≤ c 2<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup>
>
> 2<sup>k lg 2<sup>m</sup></sup> ≤ 2<sup>2<sup>m</sup></sup>
>
> 2<sup>km</sup> ≤ 2<sup>2<sup>m</sup></sup>

And, since 2<sup>n</sup> is a monotonically-increasing function, this is equivalent to

> km ≤ 2<sup>m</sup>

Now, let's finish things off.  Let's suppose that we let m = max{k, 4}, so k ≤ m.  Thus we have that

> km ≤ m<sup>2</sup>

We also have that

> m<sup>2</sup> ≤ 2<sup>m</sup>

Since for any m ≥ 4, m<sup>2</sup> ≤ 2<sup>m</sup>, and we've ensured by our choice of m that m = max{k, 4}.  Combining this, we get that

> km ≤ 2<sup>m</sup>

Which is equivalent to what we wanted to show above.  Consequently, if we pick any n ≥ 2<sup>m</sup> = 2<sup>max{4, k}</sup>, it will be true that n<sup>k</sup> ≤ 2<sup>n</sup>.  Thus by the formal definition of big-O notation, we get that n<sup>k</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>).

I *think* this math is right; please let me know if I'm wrong!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.But will this work for any k? In case of km<=m^2 - is this for any k?

Comment: @user629034- Yes, this works for any k.  The idea is to pick the value of m (and thus of n0) based on the value of k that's picked.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I will make this an answer.

Instead of reducing the equation like you have been trying to do, you should try to find an `n0` and a `M` that satisfy the formal definition of big O notation found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

Something along the lines of `n0=M=k` might work (I haven't written it out so maybe that doesn't work, thats just to give you an idea)